# using Interop.SHDocVw.dll Where can i find this namespace/dll at?

Tags: dll, reference, webbrowser-control, namespaces, shdocvw

I've done this before, I don't remember if i downloaded the DLL from off the net or something but i don't want to get a virus. I need access to this namespace so that I can have extra features that the Webbrowswer control doesn't offer.

How do I add a Com reference exactly. Or do I need the dll from someplace

Thanks

Comment: Another point to consider if you're having issues: use strictly x86, not AnyCPU.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433990/watin-system-io-filenotfoundexception-interop-shdocvw - it may already be referenced just needs to be Embed=false & Copy Local=true

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a reference to Microsoft Internet Controls COM object, anyway you can add features like in this example: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=115195

Comment: Dead link. Any chance of updating it?

Comment: or you can get it created by adding reference to the shdocvw.dll found in %systemroot% which is usually "c:\windows\System32\shdocvw.dll"